Containing a graphic to the text block when aspect ratios differ?
There's probably a better way of asking this, if I knew the correct terms, but ...
If one wants to display a graphic within the text block only, such that the document page still has a header and footer, but the aspect ratio of the graphic may differ from that of the text block, other than trial and error, is this the correct way to ask for something like "contain" to set the size to largest of textwidth or textheight, whichever is reached first?
It appears to have worked and removed the hbox and vbox overflow warnings.
Thank you.
\includegraphics[
  width=\textwidth,
  totalheight=\textheight,
  keepaspectratio=true
]{p42.pdf}


yes. ..........

@cfr Thank you.
